# Why is the rate of solvolysis of t-butyl chloride lesser than that of 1-chloro-1-methylcyclohexane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability, hydrolysis

I came across a question regarding relative rate of solvolysis. According to the answer key:

> [image]

**My analysis:**

As in all the three cases, the Cl atom is bounded to a tertiary carbon, hence, all of them are ${S_N1}$ reactions. So, the rate of solvolysis will depend on the stability of the carbocation formed. Upon considering hyperconjugation, t-Bu cation is coming out to be more stable than the tertiary cycloalkyl carbocations.

But, according to the given answer, t-BuCl has the least solvolysis rate as compared to the others. Could anyone please explain why is it so?

Comment: @NisargBhavsar Even I thought the same initially, and so to confirm, I checked if solvolysis/hydrolysis can involve elimination - In Wikipedia, for hydrolysis, it is mentioned that "The term is used broadly for substitution, **elimination**, and solvation reactions in which water is the nucleophile". So I think even if we consider E1 instead of ${S_N1}$, we still need to check the carbocation stability to compare. Am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: You are right. Check the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the definition given by *The IUPAC Compendium of Chemical Terminology: The Gold Book<sup>[[1]](https://doi.org/10.1351/goldbook)</sup>*, solvolysis is defined as:

> Generally, reaction with a solvent, or with a lyonium ion or lyate ion
> involving the rupture of one or more bonds in the reacting solute.
> More specifically the term is used for substitution elimination and
> fragmentation reactions in which a solvent species is the nucleophile.

It clearly states that elimination occurring due to a solvent is also considered solvolysis and thus elimination in case of t-butyl is also considered.

This means you are right in your reasoning of t-butyl being the most susceptible to solvolysis among the given choices.

I believe this was an error from the question setter. They must have been referring to the substitution reaction due to the solvent but ended up creating a poorly worded question.

---

**Reference:**

<sup>[(1)](https://doi.org/10.1351/goldbook) *The IUPAC Compendium of Chemical Terminology: The Gold Book*; Gold, V., Ed.; International Union of Pure and Applied Chemistry (IUPAC): Research Triangle Park, NC, 2019.</sup>